# bitcoin-cli importmulti readonly address "This type of wallet does not support this command"

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, bitcoin-core-development, bitcoin-cli

I used to tapscript to generate a taproot address thus I don't know what the related xpub key would be so I can't easily import a descriptor. I know that bitcoin-cli version 21 was able to watch a readonly address with the following command:

```
 bitcoin-cli importmulti '[{"scriptPubKey": {"address": "bcrt1pp375ce9lvxs8l9rlsl78u4szhqa7za748dfhtjj5ht05lufu4dwsshpxl6"},"timestamp":1662835676}]' '{"rescan":false}'
```

However, the same command for bitcoin version 23 returns the following error

**"This type of wallet does not support this command"**

How can I rewrite the command above to watch a read-only address in bitcoin version 23? just like in bitcoin version 21

---

[image: getdescriptorinfo]

[image: createwallet]

[image: importdescriptors]

after getting the correct descriptor, creating a wallet, and importing the descriptor we are still getting the following error.

Comment: specifically referring to this repo https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git

Answer (score 5):

The software version is unrelated to this error. You get this error because the target wallet is a Descriptor wallet (which exist prior to 23.0). `importmulti` is not allowed to be used with descriptor wallets. However you can use `importdescriptors`.

Not all descriptors must have xpubs. If you know the spending conditions for the address (internal key, tapscripts, and the tapscript tree), then you can create a `tr()` descriptor with normal pubkeys.

Otherwise you can create an `addr()` descriptor and import that instead. That would be `addr(bcrt1pp375ce9lvxs8l9rlsl78u4szhqa7za748dfhtjj5ht05lufu4dwsshpxl6)`.

Note that you may need to create a new wallet with the "Disable Private Keys" option.

---

The full command that you should use is

```
bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=mywallet importdescriptors '[{"desc":"addr(bcrt1pp375ce9lvxs8l9rlsl78u4szhqa7za748dfhtjj5ht05lufu4dwsshpxl6)#ngm593tu","timestamp":"now"}]'
```

You do not need to specify `internal`, `watchonly`, or `active`. You have currently specified `"active": true` which is incorrect as such a descriptor cannot be used as an active descriptor (i.e. it cannot be used to create new addresses).

Comment: bitcoin@backend1:/$ bitcoin-cli importdescriptors '[{ "desc": "addr(bcrt1pp375ce9lvxs8l9rlsl78u4szhqa7za748dfhtjj5ht05lufu4dwsshpxl6)",

Comment: "timestamp":1662835676, "internal": true }]'
[
  {
    "success": false,
    "error": {
      "code": -5,
      "message": "Missing checksum"
    }
  }
]

Comment: The first comment yields the result above what would be the checksum? that's missing

Comment: @AshleyHendricskon get complete descriptor with checksum using `bitcoin-cli getdescriptorinfo "addr(bcrt1pp375ce9lvxs8l9rlsl78u4szhqa7za748dfhtjj5ht05lufu4dwsshpxl6)"`

Comment: I added my comment to the "answer" above as I can't post images in the comment section

Comment: @AshleyHendricskon Please add additional information to your question rather than to a fake answer. Your question has an "Edit" link below it. It is also far better to add text rather than images of text.